# I want to delete the IDs that have no information in the remaining columns

Tags: r, missing-data

Here is a representation of my dataset:

```
Number<-c(1:10)
AA<-c(head(LETTERS,4), rep(NA,6))
BB<-c(head(letters,6), rep(NA,4))
CC<-c(1:6, rep(NA,4))
DD<-c(10:14, rep(NA,5))
EE<-c(3:8, rep(NA,4))
FF<-c(6:1, rep(NA,4))
mydata<-data.frame(Number,AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,FF)
```

I want to delete all the IDs `(Number)` that have no information in the remaining columns, automatically. I want to tell the function that if there is a value in `Number` but there is only `NA` in all the remaining columns, delete the row.
I must have the dataframe below:

```
   Number   AA   BB CC DD EE FF
1       1    A    a  1 10  3  6
2       2    B    b  2 11  4  5
3       3    C    c  3 12  5  4
4       4    D    d  4 13  6  3
5       5 <NA>    e  5 14  7  2
6       6 <NA>    f  6 NA  8  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `if_all/if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
   filter(if_any(-Number, complete.cases))
```

-output

```
  Number   AA BB CC DD EE FF
1      1    A  a  1 10  3  6
2      2    B  b  2 11  4  5
3      3    C  c  3 12  5  4
4      4    D  d  4 13  6  3
5      5 <NA>  e  5 14  7  2
6      6 <NA>  f  6 NA  8  1
```

or

```
mydata %>%
   filter(!if_all(-Number, is.na))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
 subset(mydata, rowSums(!is.na(mydata[-1])) >0 )
  Number   AA BB CC DD EE FF
1      1    A  a  1 10  3  6
2      2    B  b  2 11  4  5
3      3    C  c  3 12  5  4
4      4    D  d  4 13  6  3
5      5 <NA>  e  5 14  7  2
6      6 <NA>  f  6 NA  8  1
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possible base R solution:

```
mydata[rowSums(is.na(mydata[,-1])) != ncol(mydata[,-1]), ]
```

**Output**

```
  Number   AA BB CC DD EE FF
1      1    A  a  1 10  3  6
2      2    B  b  2 11  4  5
3      3    C  c  3 12  5  4
4      4    D  d  4 13  6  3
5      5 <NA>  e  5 14  7  2
6      6 <NA>  f  6 NA  8  1
```

Or we could use `apply`:

```
mydata[!apply(mydata[,-1], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))),]
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution, using `janitor::remove_empty`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

inner_join(mydata, remove_empty(mydata[-1], which = "rows"))

#> Joining, by = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF")
#>   Number   AA BB CC DD EE FF
#> 1      1    A  a  1 10  3  6
#> 2      2    B  b  2 11  4  5
#> 3      3    C  c  3 12  5  4
#> 4      4    D  d  4 13  6  3
#> 5      5 <NA>  e  5 14  7  2
#> 6      6 <NA>  f  6 NA  8  1
```

Comment: This will remove rows with *any* `NA`s. I think the OP is asking to remove rows that have *all* `NA`s (in the other columns).

Comment: You are right, @r2evans! Thanks for calling my attention to that. I am going to modify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df <- df[,colSums(is.na(df))<nrow(df)]
```

This makes a copy of your data though. If you have a large dataset then you can use:

```
Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x)), df)
```

and depending on your approach you can use

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[,which(unlist(lapply(DT, function(x)!all(is.na(x))))),with=F]
```

If you want to use a data.table which is usually a pretty solid go-to

Comment: Your code is working per-column, not per-row as the OP requested.

Comment: oops I misread the question.